# jquery how to use a select list to redirect to new pages?

Tags: jquery

i am trying to create a select list and when a user selects an option it will go to a html page

```
<select name="test" id="test">
<option value="about.html">about</option>
<option value="portfolio.html">portfolio</option>
</select>
```

i am trying to imitate this ul:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="about.html">about</a></li>
    <li><a href="portfolio.html">portfolio</a></li>
</ul>
```

any ideas?
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#test').change(function(){
    window.location.href = $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: great. this works. but the value from the list changes to the first option. How to keep the option that i selected ?

Answer (score 2):

An inline example:

```
<select onchange="location.href = this.value;">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="http://www.google.com">google</option>
    <option value="http://www.yahoo.com">yahoo</option>
</select>
```

Also, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/RJ5qD/1/)'s the example fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#test").bind("change", function() {
      location.href = $(this).val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('#test').change(function() {

var page = $(this).val();
window.location.replace(page);

       });
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way to it (I mean: accessible, that works without js too), is to have a form anyway (with also a "Go" button that will submit the form. You could hide the button though). The idea behind this system is that on the "change" event of the select you will submit() the form. Server side you will then redirect the user to the page you need.

Comment: I agree there should be a form fallback that can still be used without JavaScript, but when js IS available, why not save the bandwidth and redirect client-side?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#test").change(function () {
  $(location).attr('href', $(this).val());
});
```